# Javascript to get value of one item in a list of items in html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I have a list of items, which have inputs that are hidden but all contain different values, 
How do i get the value from each li

```
<ul class="happiness">
 <li><input type="hidden" value="guid-xxxx0"/> Happy </li>
 <li><input type="hidden" value="guid-xxxx1"/> Sad </li>
 <li><input type="hidden" value="guid-xxxx2"/> I dont know </li>
</ul>
```

Is this the right way to do it?

```
$(".happiness").click(function(){
 var value = $(this).find("li input").val();
});
```

Comment: How to click if its invisible??

Comment: i mistakenly left out just any text in the Li's thanx for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a click event to the `li` to update the `#displayer` content with the value the element contains.  I assume that in practice the `<li>` will have more contents.

For example:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'), function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.getElementById('displayer').textContent =
            this.querySelector('input').value;
    });
});
```

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/UGuX2/), but it does make some assumptions such as each `li` having only one `input` descendant.

Comment: I was considering this silly, but you made it, and that too, using pure JS!!